# How do I find the P value and Z score?

Tags: statistics

The question goes like this: In a study of MP3 player popularity, 20% of people in a random sample of 1100 Americans age 12 and older indicated that they owned an MP3 player. The owners were 24% of the males and 16% of the females. Suppose that there were the same number of males and females in the sample of 1100. Find the Z-score and P-value.

I've been stuck for an hour or so. Please help! I know I need to calculate the standard deviation, but I don't understand how to do that without being given actual values?

Comment: We might be missing information. This just seems ambiguous. Are we looking at the distribution of MP3 players by gender? If so, we may be able to do this.

Comment: @SeanRoberson That's all the question says, I copied it exactly word for word. I assume that's what the distribution is, but that's all the question said.

Answer (score 1):

Easy hypothesis test problem. They all follow the same formula.

First, since we're dealing with proportions, we know that the population proportion $P$ is distributed as $\mathcal{N}(np, p(1-p)/n)$ - that is, it follows a normal distribution with mean $np$ and variance $\frac{p(1-p)}{n}$. Anyway, enough theory. Here's what we do.

Look at the claim - the previous study. Because of ambiguity (we can work around this, sort of), let's say $20\%$ of the target group owns an MP3 player. We'll test to see if, in these two samples (independently), if the true ownership is different than $20\%$.

For the first group of $550$ males (it says the sample sizes are the same), the sample proportion is $24\%$. We compute the z-score $z_M$ as

$$ z_M = \frac{0.24 - 0.2}{\sqrt{ \frac{0.2 \cdot 0.8}{550} } } $$

and so $z_M = 2.35$. We'll now look in a table for the z-score $-2.35$, as we can just multiply the corresponding area by $2$ to give the p-value. This p-value for this group is $0.019774$. This is less than $0.05$, so we can reject the hypothesis that the true ownership is $0.2$ of the population.

The same can be done for female owners. Can you take it from here?

Comment: I can do it for females, but then my question is what is the overall Z-score and P-value? It only wants one value and I don't understand how to get one value from two tests. Sorry if that's a stupid question, I'm already failing the class.

Comment: I'm not sure at all. We can look at the difference and do something weird, but it may be beyond the scope of what you know now.